# Polygon limit scenekit

Tags: scenekit

I remember reading that scenekit has a polygon limit of 200k. However I haven't been able to find the source where I read it, so I have no idea if it's current information or even correct at all.

It may have been a wwdc session, either way what I need to know is;

Is this correct?
Is this limitation on the entire scene or just what is being rendered at any one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think SceneKit has a hard limit on the number of polygons it will render. Instead, you'll see a gradual performance falloff as that number (and other measures of CPU and GPU usage) goes up. 200,000 is probably well into that falloff on some devices and perfectly fine on others.

You might be thinking about some of the advice in the WWDC 2014 session "Building a Game with SceneKit". That talk shows several metrics you can use to gauge a SceneKit app's performance and strategies for dealing with different kinds if bottlenecks. I'd recommend watching the [video](http://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos) if you haven't already.

Comment: Spot on, exactly where I had read it. Just for reference, he explains that Apple's sample code 'Bananas' has 200k polygons in the entire scene and only 80k are ever rendered at once. In his words this is "reasonable numbers".